# Execute a Scala action inside an Java Controller (PlayFramework)

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.2, securesocial

I've create an app using the Playfrawork with Java.

And I'm using the SecureSocial plugin on it.
Inside my controller there is a method that one of the process of it is to execute the handle start reset password inside the SecureSocial.
But that method is written in Scala.

If I refer the method inside my Java source like this:

```
Registration.handleStartResetPassword();
```

Nothing happens! Same if I change to the following line:

```
Registration.handleStartResetPassword().apply();
```

Same as the following source code block:

```
play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee<byte[], SimpleResult> it = Registration.handleStartResetPassword().apply(ctx()._requestHeader());
Future<SimpleResult> future = it.run();
Option<Try<SimpleResult>> result = future.value();
SimpleResult res = result.get().get();
```

I removed all my code and just tried to execute the Secure Social code but nothing happens.
Here is my method:

```
public static Result resetPassword() {
    Registration.handleStartResetPassword().apply();
    return TODO;
}
```

My route is this one:

```
POST    /reset    controllers.ProfileController.resetPassword
```

---

Edited: Added another way that I've tried to run but just didm't got the method running.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `handleStartResetPassword()` you get an instance of `Action` back, it doesn't actually do anything until you to feed it with a particular request by calling `Action.apply(request)` which will then actually run the logic for that controller action and return a `Future<Result>`.

Not entirely sure if you can bridge backwards and get a play Java async result out of that though.

Comment: And how can I get an instance of import play.api.mvc.Request<AnyContent> that the method demands? If I use the method "request()" from the controller class it return to me an instance of play.mvc.Http.Request.

Comment: Didn't think of that, my final sentence goes for that one as well. A quick look at play.mvc.Http.Request didn't give me any obvious ways to access the underlying Request object from Java.

Comment: That's the point, using the logic, your answer has a really good logic because the method apply that receive an Request return a Future.

I've tried the following code but it just didn't run the method on scala. 


    play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee<byte[], SimpleResult> it = Registration.handleStartResetPassword().apply(ctx()._requestHeader());
    Future<SimpleResult> future = it.run();
    Option<Try<SimpleResult>> result = future.value();
    SimpleResult res = result.get().get();

Comment: I added the source code oh the first post. because in comments it is not possible to read it.

Comment: Well, I Created a Scala controller so it was easier to run the method inside the SecureSocial. But the question remains. How can I do that?